# Javascript onclick(): Why doesn't it work correctly in Firefox or IE?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have 3 `<p>` elements in the HTML and a "replacement" button which will replace these elements with a corresponding "alert button".  I have Javascript create these three alert buttons and I'm trying to get these buttons to work with onclick().

Originally, my method was basically to call a function which contains all the onclick() events and attach to all of them.  It works - however, in Firefox and IE, if you click the replacement button again, the alert buttons will stop working for some reason (as in, clicking on them will do nothing).  Chrome does not have this issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zj5B4/

So I went with a second method and grabbed the number buttons first via getElementsByTagName and assign each alert button their onclick() event.  This works perfectly in all browsers (as in, even if you click on the replace button multiple times, the alert buttons will stay activate upon clicked).

http://jsfiddle.net/zS7Tk/

So my question is: Why doesn't the first method work as it should?

Comment: Your first method works for me on Chrome, FF 25.0.1, IE10 & IE9(simulated).

Comment: I am using Firefox 22.0 and IE8.  If what you say is true, I guess it's an issue with old browsers?